# How to get request value if a variable appears several times?

Tags: python, request, pyramid

For example, the URL request is like this:

http://any-server.org/cgi-bin/test.cgi?a=1&b=2&b=20&b=200

Is it possible to get three values of b as a list`[2,20,200]` in CGI or any web framework?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Any web framework' yet you tagged this with Pyramid? What is it to be?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just not sure whether only specific web framework supports this feature..

Comment: Although different *python* frameworks may have a different API to handle this situation, all that I am aware of, do handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.getall()`](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/interfaces.html#pyramid.interfaces.IMultiDict):

```
b = request.GET.getall('b')  # ['2', '20', '200']
```

`.getall()` is a method on the `MultiDict` class; various parameters of `request`, including [`.GET`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.GET), [`.POST`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.POST) and `.params` are `MultiDict` instances. The [`WebOb` project documentation](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#query-post-variables) (on which the Pyramid request is based) can provide more information.

Comment: You mean `request.GET.getall('b')`, or `request.params.getall(..)` or `request.POST.getall(...)`. `request` itself is not a `MultiDict`. :-)

Comment: @MichaelMerickel: :-P Corrected.

Answer (score -1):

Which language are you using?

The above will work as you expect in .NET, I expected is similar in php and other languages.

// Expanded the answer following feedback

ASP.NET seems to group the values into a comma seperated list, but the real way of doing this should be as `file.html?a=1&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]3`. This should then get translated as an array of values by the server.

You can also use `file.html?a=1&b=1,2,3`. This will translate into string on the server, and can be split on comma to get an array.

Comment: I can't say for sure what you've said is incorrect in .NET, but I think it might be. for the url query string ?a=1&b=2&b=20&b=200 the following code will print **a: 1 b: 200** `foreach($_GET as $key => $val) { print $key . ": " . $val . " "; }`

Comment: Pyramid is a python framework, it has a dedicated API for multiple values with the same keyword.